# Completely replace Angular component tag with its template

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm creating some custom logic in an Angular site that server-side renders out into another templating service [long story] to then get rendered to the client.  In doing so, I want to wrap the logic for the other templating service in some components and then have the component's template effectively replace itself so it just renders out its template.

Given:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-test',
    template '{{ post_name }}',
})
export class PostTestComponent { }
```

and then

```
...
<app-test></app-test>
...
```

The output ends up being:

```
...
<app-test>{{ post_name }}</app-test>
...
```

But what I want is:

```
...
{{ post_name }}
...
```

Is there a way to achieve this?  Because of some boring annoying legacy stuff, I'm still on Angular 6.1.x. But if there's a way to achieve this with 7 or 8 etc, please let me know - it's possible that might outweigh the legacy cruft.

Comment: You could use a directive on a different wrapper element if that's an option. Still has to be put on a tag but if you have a div or something else wrapping that component you could put it on that and it won't render that `<app-test>` tag.

Comment: I left a comment on the first answer - I had considered that, but because it's going to be outputting templating logic, it'd break some stuff to do that

Answer (score 2):

Best I can come up with is creating a directive-like component like so:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '[app-my]',
  template: '{{myprop}}'
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  @Input() myprop: string;

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<div app-my [myprop]="'test'"></div>
```

Rendered html:

```
<div _ngcontent-hfa-c42="" app-my="" ng-reflect-myprop="test">test</div>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkc42e)

Thanks to @Eliseo I removed the `div` prefix, because that is not necessary.

Comment: why use as selector div[app-my]? if you use simple `[app-my]` you get the same result

Comment: Thanks! I had thought about using a directive, but ultimately because I need to output some templating logic, having the div there is going to cause me some headaches

Comment: @SteveKanter what do you mean under "output some templating logic" and "headaches"

Comment: @Sergey my use-case is I want to effectively render out some templatic logic for a 3rd party platform [Hubspot] from an Angular app. The templates have tags like `{% asd %}` and `{{ asd }}`. I don't want Angular to render these out, and I've found ways around that, but if I output this logic inside of a component [effectively a div] and that runs logic in Hubspot's end, I could end up with an opening div tag but no closing. I know the use-case is weird and not at all typical, but it's what I got.

Comment: If the problem is only about {% asd %} and {{ asd }} you could change the interpolation symbols to that not interfering with template engine's

Comment: @Eliseo Thanks, I didn't know that. I will update my answer.

Comment: @Sergey hmm that's a possible option to solve the root issue, albeit I'd still love to be able to segment out the logic such that I can have the component programmatically generate the logic for me. How would I go about changing the interpolation symbols?

Comment: @SteveKanter https://angular.io/api/core/Component#interpolation. Also you could have a look at Angular elements (it's like custom webcomponents that get compiled and instantiated via simple tags)